# Print Labels from Javascript on DYMO 550 Turbo

Tags: javascript, dymo

I have a project there i want to print label with computername and serialnumber on a templatefile on a DYMO 550 Turbo printer.

When i bougt the printer i was hoping to use Powershell to solve it, but i´ve figured out that then they introduced the 500 series it not support Powershell any longer, Only Javascript or C++.

I´m not familar with java or C++ :(

I´ve found this link https://github.com/dymosoftware/dymo-connect-framework .

If i run this line code in Visual Studio Code

```
dymo.label.framework.init() //Initialize DYMO Label Framework
```

i´ve got this.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe .\Test.js Uncaught
> ReferenceError ReferenceError: dymo is not defined
> at  (undefined:1:1)
> at Module._compile (undefined:1126:14)
> at Module._extensions..js (undefined:1180:10)
> at Module.load (undefined:1004:32)
> at Module._load (undefined:839:12)
> at executeUserEntryPoint (undefined:81:12)
> at  (undefined:17:47) Process exited with code 1

I have installed all the SDK.

Anyone got an idea?